# ASP.NET - Use Column Name Instead of Index In GridViewRowEventArgs Row.Cells.Item

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I want to perform some simple auto-formatting to the cells in my GridView.  So far, I have the following code:

```
Private Sub gridviewRefreshPanel_RowDataBound( _
    ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) _
        Handles gridviewRefreshPanel.RowDataBound

    Dim readyStatus As String = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "READY")

    Select Case readyStatus
        Case "NO"
            e.Row.Cells.Item(5).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            e.Row.Cells.Item(5).Font.Bold = True
        Case "N/A"
            e.Row.Cells.Item(5).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Goldenrod
            e.Row.Cells.Item(5).Font.Bold = True
        Case "YES"
            e.Row.Cells.Item(5).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.DarkGreen
            e.Row.Cells.Item(5).Font.Bold = True
    End Select

End Sub
```

I'd like to refer to the cells by the column name rather than the index.  For example, DataRow:

```
row.Item("ON_TIME")
```

How do I achieve this with a GridView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do like.. but this is c# code

```
DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
dr["ColumnName"]
```

**Edit:** Put this condition at the top

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Referenced object has a value of 'Nothing'." when I try that.

Comment: Why do I always forget the header column? With your help, it works now.  I'm using "dr.Table.Columns("ON_TIME").Ordinal" to get the index number.